# minted and Unicode: symbols missing

Tags: xetex, minted

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}[mathescape,
                   linenos,
                   numbersep=5pt,
                   gobble=2,
                   frame=lines,
                   framesep=2mm]{csharp}
      string title = "This is a Unicode π in the sky"
      /*
      Defined as $\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{d}$ where $P$ is the perimeter
      of an $n$-sided regular polygon circumscribing a
      circle of diameter $d$.
      */
      const double pi = 3.1415926535
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Note the missing π in the `title` variable.

Using latest versions of packages from MikTeX distribution with XeLaTeX.

Comment: You get `Missing character: There is no π in font cmtt10` in the log. But if you load `fontspec`, you get `Missing character: There is no π in font [lmmono10-regular]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a font problem, not a LaTeX engine or `Pygments`.

Choosing another font will result in a proper output:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmonofont{Consolas}
```

Expected output:

[image: result]

Comment: Or `\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}`. Using XeLaTeX without `fontspec` is not recommended.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks! Didn't know about Unicode version of Computer Modern!